# php code to access part of object

Tags: php, arrays, json, object

I have a code which returns the following object:

```
{"ok":true,"result":{"file_id":"AwADBAADrAADmmT8BE_FGiduk6tZAg","file_size":106562,"file_path":"voice\/file_1.oga"}}
```

I want to access the last part (i.e `voice\/file_1.oga`) and store it in a variable called `$path`.

I have tried `json_decode()` but I believe the object is not a JSON as it does not have square brackets.
Help is appreciated!

Comment: It works for me: https://paste.fedoraproject.org/408111/15615514/

Comment: You used json_decode() and you were able to store the file_path?
if so can you please post your code? Cheers!

Comment: @NehalJ.Wani, Thank you for your help, I stored the path using your code and the following:
`$path= $a["result"]["file_path"];`